# How do I change 2 columns in database?

Tags: php, sql, database

So I have been trying to find a way to update 2 columns in 1 database using the same information. So for example, I have one column called payout and one called totalpayout and I have a postback link that updates payout but I am trying to figure a way to update totalpayout. So when `http://example.com/postback.php?affsub={theirid}&payout=10` gets accessed it updates payout and totalpayout. Heres the code that updates payout and I don't know how to update totalpayout with it.

```
<?php

define("MYSQL_HOST", "localhost");
define("MYSQL_PORT", "3306");
define("MYSQL_DB", "db");
define("MYSQL_TABLE", "tbl");
define("MYSQL_USER", "user");
define("MYSQL_PASS", "pass");
$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS, MYSQL_DB);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
$affsub =            $_GET['affsub'];
$payout =           $_GET['payout'];


if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".MYSQL_DB.".".MYSQL_TABLE." SET payout=payout+(?) WHERE affsub=(?) "))) 
{
  echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
$stmt->bind_param('ds', $payout, $affsub );
if (!$stmt->execute()) 
{
  echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
else
{
  printf("%d Row updated, added ".$payout." to locker ".$affsub." .\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update two column with `SET` statement by add comma between them. So you can use `SET payout=payout+(?), totalpayout=totalpayout+(?)`.

***Note:*** I assumed `totalpayout` increase by `$payout`. Edit it based on your algorithm to increasing `totalpayout`.

```
<?php

define("MYSQL_HOST", "localhost");
define("MYSQL_PORT", "3306");
define("MYSQL_DB", "db");
define("MYSQL_TABLE", "tbl");
define("MYSQL_USER", "user");
define("MYSQL_PASS", "pass");
$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS, MYSQL_DB);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
$affsub =            $_GET['affsub'];
$payout =           $_GET['payout'];


if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".MYSQL_DB.".".MYSQL_TABLE." SET payout=payout+(?), totalpayout=totalpayout+(?) WHERE affsub=(?) "))) 
{
  echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
$stmt->bind_param('dds', $payout, $payout, $affsub );
if (!$stmt->execute()) 
{
  echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
else
{
  printf("%d Row updated, added ".$payout." to locker ".$affsub." .\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));
}
?>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked, please accept this answer. @awesomexbox3

Comment: i had to wait like 7 minutes but im doing that now